# How to check whether a HDF5 path name its a group or a dataset?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I need to iterate over all children and attributes tarting at a given hdf5 path, e.g. /Group1/dataset1/ or /Group1/Subgroup2/ using the HDF5 c++ API. For this I want to write a function

```
Error HDF5File::listChildren(const string &location)
```

which will be called recursively.

More specifically, my problem is how to know whether a location is a group or a dataset.

It would work, if my file would contain only groups, then I would simply start like this:

```
Error HDF5File::listChildren(const string &location) {
 try {
   Group group = _file.openGroup(location);
```

But obviously this will fail, if under location there will be a dataset

How can I make a recursive function which works as well for groups and datasets?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not required to use a specific HDF5 library, you may want to check [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com).

Using HDFql in C++, you can solve your question like this:

```
// retrieve all objects (i.e. groups, datasets, attributes, soft and external links)
// stored in group "/Group1/Subgroup2" recursively (NOTE: you can also retrieve objects 
// stored in dataset "/Group1/dataset1" but only attributes are returned since a dataset
// cannot store groups, other datasets, soft or external links)
HDFql::execute("SHOW /Group1/Subgroup2 LIKE **");


// retrieve object name (from HDFql cursor) and print it
while(HDFql::cursorNext() == HDFql::Success)
{
   std::cout << "Object name: " << HDFql::cursorGetChar() << std::endl;
}
```

Additional information on how to retrieve objects can be found in HDFql [quick start](http://www.hdfql.com/quickstart), [examples](http://www.hdfql.com/examples) and [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of HDFql. This is interesting. Still, I would like to know about the standard way using the Standard HDF5 library, preferably the c++ api.